# How is a sphinxql query evaluated / interpretated?

Tags: sphinx

Suppose i have a sphinx index named "worldcities" with the with the following fields / attributes:

country_id  # int attribute

city        # text field

accent_city # text field

and i run the following sphinxql query:

```
SELECT * FROM worldcities WHERE country_id = 16 AND MATCH((@(city,accent_city) "New Yor*"))
```

How does sphinx evaluates the query?:
Is it first searching through all the records and then filters the results by countr_id:
"give me all the results that start with 'New Yor' and the filter them by country_id"?

Or does it filter first by country id and the searches through the results:
"give me all the results that have countr_id = 16 then search in those"?

Hope i made myself clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "give me all the results that start with 'New Yor' and the filter them by country_id"

this one.

The full-text queries runs first. Then the filters 'exclude' non required matches.

btw, your query is missing some quotes, should be

```
MATCH('@(city,accent_city) "New Yor*"')
```

Match function takes a string.

Comment: yes, i figured that out eventually. It isn't a production query, just an example. Thanks for the answer.